# GCC fprintf: should that be an int (32bit) or char (8bit)?

Tags: c, gcc, printf, scanf

Which of the codes would be valid? I am getting zero characters on the outputs and wonder if that is caused by some mishandling of chars as integers or vice versa. The %c specifier is what should be printed, I am just not sure about the last argument.

```
int c;
fprintf(stdout, "%c", c);
int n;
fprintf(stdout, "%c", n);
```

Same question regarding the scanf, should that be a char or int or either?

Comment: `%c` is for chars.

Comment: @tkausl `%c` and `%d` both take `int` as input, they differ in what is output

Comment: Are you asking what the valid range of values is for `c`?

Comment: @tkausl  That is exactly what I was asking. Would the same be for fscanf?

Comment: If you are having problem with some code then post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @tkausl: "`%c` is for chars" -- That's a little misleading. `%c` requires an `int` argument and prints its value as a character. If you pass a `char` argument, it will be promoted to `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are okay. The ISO C11 standard states in `7.21.6.1 The fprintf function /9` (all the various `*printf` and `*scanf` calls are defined in terms of `fprintf` and `fscanf`) that:

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

But, in the section for `%c` (`/8`), it also states (my emphasis):

> If no `l` length modifier is present, the ***`int`*** argument is converted to an `unsigned char`, and the resulting character is written.

In fact, passing an `int` or a `char` makes no difference since default argument promotions are performed on varargs-type functions beyond the ellipses (as per `6.5.2.2 Function calls /6` and `/7` and `6.3 Conversions`)

> ... ***the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have type float are promoted to double. These are called the default argument promotions.***
>
> The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. ***The default argument
>   promotions are performed on trailing arguments.***
>
> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), ***the value is converted to an int;*** otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the integer promotions.

So, since `fprintf` is defined thus:

```
int fprintf(FILE * restrict stream, const char * restrict format, ...);
```

it means a `char` argument will be upgraded to an `int` anyway.

---

The `fscanf` is another matter. It states, in `7.21.6.2 The fscanf function /12` (again, my emphasis):

> If no `l` length modifier is present, the corresponding argument shall be a
>   pointer to the initial element of a ***character*** array large enough to accept the sequence. No null character is added.

That means you should be providing the address of a *character* (or character array). If you provide an `int` and it's not the same size, you're likely to see only *part* of that `int` changed and the rest will be left as some arbitrary value. For example, on an eight-bit byte, four-byte `int`, big-endian system:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| 0x12 | 0x34 | 0x56 | 0x78 | <- Initial value of int 0x12345678
+------+------+------+------+
| 0x36 | .... | .... | .... | <- Read character '6' (0x36 in ASCII)
+------+------+------+------+
| 0x36 | 0x34 | 0x56 | 0x78 | <- Final value of int 0x36345678
+------+------+------+------+
```

You can see that the *other* bytes of the `int` remain untouched (represented by `....`), resulting in the final value of the `int` being something *other* than `0x36`.